# Unity C# Run a Random StartCoroutine stored in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I have a dictionary on a C# Unity file, of type **Dictionary<string,IEnumerator> dic**.
I'd like to select a random string, match it to an enumerator, and run the coroutine.

**The tricky part is my dictionary is located in a different script,** so I'm not really sure how to do that.

I did try **passing in the Enumerator's string** but that didn't work + I have to pass parameters.

I also tried accessing the enumerators by directly accessing the property keys as such:

**StartCoroutine(File2.enumerator1())**, where File2 is my other file and enumerator1 is 1 of the random enumerators I'm trying to call, but that won't be too effective because Idk which enumerator is selected, and thus can't specify the property..

Any ideas?

thx

Comment: Give code, please.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have access to, and the ability to modify the code relating to the Dictionary? If so, you could try another approach. This is what your second file could like like (edited to demonstrate my reason for using a `Func`):

```
    private Dictionary<string, Func<string, IEnumerator>> _functions;
    private string [ ] _directions = { "North", "South", "East", "West" };

    private void Start ( )
    {
        _functions = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, IEnumerator>>
        {
            [ "North" ] = North,
            [ "South" ] = South,
            [ "East" ] = East,
            [ "West" ] = West
        };
    }

    public IEnumerator North ( string message ) { Debug.Log ( $"North and \"{message}\"" ); yield return null; }
    public IEnumerator South ( string message ) { Debug.Log ( $"South and \"{message}\"" ); yield return null; }
    public IEnumerator East ( string _ ) { yield return null; }
    public IEnumerator West ( string _ ) { yield return null; }

    public Func<string, IEnumerator> GetRandomRoutine ( )
    {
        var direction = _directions [ UnityEngine.Random.Range ( 0, _directions.Length ) ];
        if ( _functions.TryGetValue ( direction, out var func ) ) return func;
        return null;
    }
```

You'd then call that in your first file like this:

```
    public void SomeMethod ( )
    {
        var routine = GetRandomRoutine ( );
        StartCoroutine ( routine( "Hello!" ) );
    }
```

As suggested below, a simplified version could look like this:

```
    private Dictionary<string, IEnumerator> _functions;
    private string [ ] _directions = { "North", "South", "East", "West" };

    private void Start ( )
    {
        _functions = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerator>
        {
            [ "North" ] = North ( ),
            [ "South" ] = South ( ),
            [ "East" ] = East ( ),
            [ "West" ] = West ( )
        };
    }

    public IEnumerator North ( ) { yield return null; }
    public IEnumerator South ( ) { yield return null; }
    public IEnumerator East ( ) { yield return null; }
    public IEnumerator West ( ) { yield return null; }

    public IEnumerator  GetRandomRoutine ( )
    {
        var direction = _directions [ UnityEngine.Random.Range ( 0, _directions.Length ) ];
        if ( _functions.TryGetValue ( direction, out var func ) ) return func;
        return null;
    }
```

And be called the same way, but with no argument being passed.

Comment: You do not have to use `Func<IEnumerator>`. Simply use `IEnumerator` directly, allowing you to pass it to a `StartCoroutine` call as is and saving the invocation of another method.

Comment: How would you pass in parameters when calling GetRandomRoutine()?

Then use the parameters for each of the enumerators in the dictionary

Comment: @GoFast I modified the answer to demonstrate both my initial intention, as well as address Thomas' concerns about calling an extra method.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was really helpful and I learned quite a bit

Comment: @GoFast if the question is answered, Mark it as such and draw a line under it. Cheers.